# Place eshell prompts to the other line

Tags: emacs

My eshell prompts is

```
~ λ cd Documents/

~/Documents λ
```

How could I place to the other line as

```
~/Documents 
λ:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customize the user option `eshell-prompt-function`, `C-h v` says

> A function that returns the Eshell prompt string.
>   Make sure to update `eshell-prompt-regexp` so that it will match your
>   prompt.

For example,

```
(defun your-eshell-prompt-function ()
  (setq eshell-prompt-regexp "^λ: ")
  (format "%s\nλ: " (abbreviate-file-name (eshell/pwd))))

(setq eshell-prompt-function #'your-eshell-prompt-function)
```

By the way, if your prompt is colorful, you might want to disable `eshell-highlight-prompt`.